# Xaml ListView strange behavior (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on Windows Phone App (Windows Phone 8.1) and I have a strange behavior of my `ListView` control.

I have a `ListView` with text items (Sort of a chat) which is bound to `ReadOnlyObservebleCollection` to whom I am inserting items as I write a new message or when I receive a new one. I choose my `ListView` items template with  my `DataTemplateSelector`.

The issue:

Sometimes, when my `ListView` is empty, I add a new message to my ListView I don't see it on the screen, but I can see that it in my collection and I know for sure that the `RaisePropertyEvent` is fired.

As I continue to add new item to the collection I can scroll down the list (there is  some sort of placeholder in the first idex) and then I am seeing the rest of the items - except the first one.

I've also noticed that the missing item is getting to the `DataTemplateSelector` and it's returns the right template.

Getting weirder, when I am refreshing the view - all the items(including the first one) at their right places.

I guess there is something wrong with the first item generation but I don't get any binding exceptions or such.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your xaml for ListView control?

Comment: Well I can post some of the xaml code, but it will be a simple ListView declaration with ItemSource binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue was occurring to me in my ListView. It was happening because listview was not loaded(loaded event was not fired) at the time first item was added to my observable collection. To fix this issue I start adding items in my observable collection after listview loaded event is raised.